# Can you use substr with multiple conditions?

Tags: r, subset, substr

I have a dataframe of four columns: Time, ID, Serial, Reading.

Serial number refers to an actual serial number of an instrument I am using in my study. Each unique serial number corresponds to a physical weather station. I am therefore creating a fifth column based on what the number is in "Serial".

So far, this has worked pretty well:

```
weather[substr(weather$Serial,1,6)=="600655", "Station"]<- Station 1
```

However, sometimes our instruments were swapped between stations. Therefore, I want to be able to populate the Station column based on both Serial AND Time e.g. if the serial matches "600655" and is after August, then it will be Station 2. However, if it is before August, it will be Station 1. The format of "Time" is "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS".

Is this possible? Alternatively, is there an easier way of doing this? I have approximately 50 weather stations, and doing this for each station is quite tiresome..

Comment: Please show a small reproduccible example with `dput` and the expecte douptut

Answer (score 1):

Consider creating a separate *stations* dataframe with station name, number, and change date, then `merge` to *weather* dataframe and `subset` by time logic.

```
# NEW DATA FRAME OF ALL WEATHER STATIONS
stations <- data.frame(
    Station = c("Station 1", "Station 2", ...),
    Station_Number = c("600655", "600655", ...),
    Change_Date = as.POSIXCT("2020-07-31", "9999-12-31", ...)
)

# ADD NEW COLUMN FOR MERGING
weather$Station_Number <- substr(weather$Serial,1,6)

# MERGE AND SUBSET
final_df <- transform(
    subset(
        merge(weather, stations, by="Station_Number"),
        Time <= Change_Date
    ), 
    Change_Date=NULL, Station_Number=NULL
) # REMOVE HELPER COLUMNS

# MERGE AND SUBSET WITH BASE R PIPES (R 4.1+)
final_df <- merge(weather, stations, by="Station_Number") |>
    subset(Time <= Change_Date) |>
    transform(Change_Date=NULL, Station_Number=NULL)
```

Comment: First answer I've seen posted using base pipes! Way to be an early adopter :)